# best way to share objects between js files

Tags: javascript

I want to share this object between several files so they will be able to read and modify it.

```
obj = {id: 34234, name: 'xxxx', surname: 'yyyy'};
```

Should I import my js file into all my html files like so

```
html1.html <script src='myObj.js'></script>
html2.html <script src='myObj.js'></script>
html3.html <script src='myObj.js'></script>
...
```

or use `localstorage.setItem() / localstorage.getItem()` ? Which is the best approach?

**Obs:** *If context interests you*, it's about calling a API that returns users/projetcs/project-steps... When user logs in, I want to fetch all theirs projects. If user edit it, loads the project obj by its id and alter it and then send the change to the server. Same happen to other things like project-steps (but this is loaded into another page).

Comment: use a module pattern.

Comment: if you define it before calling files, they can call it and modify it inside files,

Comment: @AbdelrahmanGobarah I'll make a call to the API to get the users projects when user logs in and fill the data table.  If user, lets say, click in a project, it'll redirect the user to another html page that is all about the setps for the project he clicked on. There'll need to load the project steps. So how do I do it? Get from the variable or get from the localStorage? Or make another request to the API with the project id?

Comment: if the object can change with multi-users not same user, request another API to be sure the object is updated, if it can only change by this user, request it first time only and use it as a global variable,

Comment: @AbdelrahmanGobarah I got it. It'll be for single user, so best approach would be variable. Just another thing, I heard it's not so good to have global variables in js. Should I go for it anyways?

Comment: no but you can use module pattern like @DanielA.White said, and call it from anywhere, I'll give you an example in an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call this file, before any another files, if you use ajax be sure to call another functions in the **SUCCESS CALLBACK of ajax request**

```js
var commonModule = (function() {
  'use strict';
  
  var userInfo = { id: 1, name: 'go' }; // use ajax to set it if you want

  return {
    userInfo: userInfo
  };
})();

//in another file you can call 

console.log(commonModule.userInfo.name);
```

Comment: Cool, I was taking a look at this pattern right now. Seens like exact what I need. Thanks! Btw, I use fetch API